# saving changes with MoveRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I have created an app that uses a CoreData and a UITableView, and I have implemented the method MoveRowAtIndexPath to be able to shuffle my cells around, which works great. However, I would like to save my changes so when the user reloads the application the order will be saved. I have used fetch request for saving the addition/deletion of files, but whats different about saving the edited cells is that I need to save the cell position. Any tips on how to do that? I have created an attribute to my File in CoreDate called filePosition if that helps. I am very new to objective c/ iOS and not sure where to initialise my NSNumber, as if I do it in the ViewDidLoad/ViewWillAppear it will reset each time, which will effect my output.